# Confidence interval in R lm function with factors values

Tags: r, confidence-interval, lm

Does lm R function handle factors value 'correctly' when computing confidence interval ?
I read that confidence interval formula are different in case of discrete or continuous variable.

Thanks.

Philippe

Comment: Under the hood they are just treated as numerical dummies, so the formulas are the same. Yet, the interpretation for things like significance testing may be different, especially with more than 2 levels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Knarpie is right - if R encounters a factor with k levels on the right hand side of the lm() formula, it will replace it with a set of k-1 dummy variables. Once the dummy variables are included in the model, confidence intervals can be constructed for the coefficients of these dummy variables.

As an example, let's say you have an lm() model which relates the predictor Gender to Salary like so: lm(Salary ~ Gender, data = Data).

**Case 1:**

Let's assume Gender has two levels -  Male and Female - such that Female is treated as the reference level.

R will create a dummy variable D for Gender behind the scenes such that:

- D = 1 when Gender = Male;
- D = 0 when Gender = Female.

It will then fit the model

```
Salary = beta0 + beta1*D + epsilon,
```

where epsilon is an error term assumed to follow a normal distribution with mean 0 and unknown standard deviation sigma.

Given this model, you can compute a confidence interval for beta1 using the R command:

confint(lm(Salary ~ Gender, data = Data))

This will be a confidence interval for the difference in the mean values of Salary between Males and Females.

In R's notation, the dummy variable D will be referred to as GenderMale in the model summary.

**Case 2:**

Let's assume Gender has three levels -  Male, Female and Undeclared - such that Female is treated as the reference level.

R will create two dummy variables D1 and D2 for Gender behind the scenes such that:

- D1 = 1 when Gender = Male;
- D1 = 0 when Gender = Other than Male;

and

- D2 = 1 when Gender = Undeclared;
- D2 = 0 when Gender = Other than Undeclared.

It will then fit the model

```
Salary = beta0 + beta1*D1 + beta2*D2 + epsilon,
```

where epsilon is an error term assumed to follow a normal distribution with mean 0 and unknown standard deviation sigma.

Given this model, you can compute a confidence interval for beta1 and a confidence interval for beta2 using the R command:

confint(lm(Salary ~ Gender, data = Data))

The confidence interval for beta1 will represent a confidence interval for the difference in the mean values of Salary between Males and Females.

The confidence interval for beta2 will represent a confidence interval for the difference in the mean values of Salary between people with Undeclared gender and Females.

In R's notation, the dummy variable D1 will be referred to as GenderMale and the dummy variable D2 will be referred to as GenderUndeclared in the model summary.

**Addendum**

To understand the meaning of the coefficients in the model

```
Salary = beta0 + beta1*D1 + beta2*D2 + epsilon,
```

you have to use the definition of the dummy variables D1 and D2.

a) D1 = 0, D2 = 0 (Female, that is, NOT Male and NOT Undeclared)

```
Salary = beta0 + epsilon
```

b) D1 = 1, D2 = 0 (Male)

Salary = beta0 + beta1 + epsilon

c) D1 = 0, D2 = 1 (Undeclared)

Salary = beta0 + beta2 + epsilon

So beta0 represents the mean Salary for Females, beta0 + beta1 represents the mean Salary for Males and beta0 + beta2 represents the mean Salary for Undeclared.

This means that beta1 = (beta0 + beta1) - beta0 represents the difference in the mean Salary for Males versus Females.

Furthermore, beta2 = (beta0 + beta2) - beta0 represents the difference in the mean Salary for Undeclared versus Females.

Comment: thanks but why "The confidence interval for beta1 will represent a confidence interval for the difference in the mean values of Salary between Males and Females." and not "The confidence interval for beta1 will represent a confidence interval for the difference in the mean values of Salary between Males and Not Males (= Females and Undeclarred) ."

Comment: @philippe: See the Addendum above for the answer to your question.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I think I didn't get it yet... Is a confidence interval for a factor's level relative to "all the other levels" or just to an other ? Maybe we're in a specific case of a 3 levels factor ? With more than 3 it would be more relevant ?

Comment: @philippe: By default, R uses dummy coding for all factors it encounters as predictors in an lm() model. If a factor has 2 levels, R sets one level aside and treats it as a reference. It then compares the other level against the reference level. If the factor has 3 levels, R sets one level aside as a reference and compares each of the remaining levels against the reference level. More generally,  if the factor has k levels, R sets one level aside as a reference and compares each of the remaining k-1 levels against the reference level.

Comment: Assuming you have a factor with k levels as a predictor in your model and the first of these levels is set aside as a predictor, to enable the comparison of the remaining levels against the reference levels, R creates k-1 dummy variables. The coefficient of the first dummy variable facilitates the comparison of the second level against the first level. The coefficient of the second dummy variable facilitates the comparison of the third level against the first level, and so on. The comparison is done in terms of the mean value of the response variable, all else being equal.

Comment: You seem to be confused about (1) what factor levels are being compared and (2) how are the dummy variables which facilitate those comparisons defined.

Comment: For (1), with dummy coding in lm(), we always compare each of the non-reference levels of a factor against the reference level in terms of the mean value of the response variable, all else in the model being equal. For (2), the dummy variable corresponding to a specific non-reference level of a factor is defined as taking the value 1 for all records in the data where the factor assumes that level and 0 for all records in the data where the factor assumes any of the other levels.

Comment: You can read more about dummy coding in R here, for example: http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/40-regression-analysis/163-regression-with-categorical-variables-dummy-coding-essentials-in-r/

Comment: thanks for your clarification on dummy coding, but that part is already ok for me, I have difficulties to understand it in terms of confidence intervalle. May be I should read more on that. A small example here : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/386139/formula-used-in-confidence-intervalle-on-rs-lm-function