# Formula used in confidence intervalle on R's lm function

Tags: r, confidence-interval, lm

Does someone know how confidence interval on factor values are computed on R (lm function), here is a simple example :

data

`df <- data.frame(c("Male", "Female", "Male","Female"),c(900,600,1200,800))
names(df) <- c("gender","salary")
df$gender <- as.factor(df$gender)`

model

`model <- lm(salary ~ gender, data = df)`

Male confidence intervale

`predict(model, list(gender="Male"), interval = "confidence")`

`fit lwr upr 
1050 501.5172 1598.483`

Female confidence intervale

`predict(model, list(gender="Female"), interval = "confidence")`

`fit lwr upr 
700 151.5172 1248.483`

How these lower and upper bounds have been computed ?

nb : this question is linked to [Confidence interval in R lm function with factors values](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/385463/confidence-interval-in-r-lm-function-with-factors-values?noredirect=1#comment723779_385463)

Comment: Since factor variables are dummy encoded automatically, in the same way as with continuous variables. Study the source code of `predict.lm`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you are in fact estimating an ANOVA model with "treatment contrasts" (the baseline is set to "Female"). This simple ANOVA is equivalent to a simple linear regression model with some dummy-variable encoding: By running `lm()` you are in fact running a regression of $y$ on $X$, where $y=(900,600,1200,800)^T$ and $X$ is given by:
$$X=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 
1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 
 \end{pmatrix}.$$
(see `model.matrix(model)` to get $X$).

Hence, you are estimating a regression line in a simple linear regression model of the form $y= \alpha + \beta x + \epsilon_i$ and are interested in a predicition interval of the a mean response at $x=1$ (this is NOT at a new observation!).

It is well known that under the usual assumptions (including the normality assumption on $\epsilon_i$), the prediction interval for the mean response at a in-sample $x$ is then given by 
$$\widehat{y}_x \pm t_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2},n-2}SE(\widehat{y}_x),$$
where  $t_{\alpha,n}$ is the $\alpha$ quantile of a $t$-distribution with $n$-degrees of freedem, $s= \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-2}\sum_{i=1}^n e_i^2}$,  $\widehat{y}_x = \widehat{\alpha} + \widehat{\beta} x$ and $SE(\widehat{y})$ is given by::
$$SE(\widehat{y}_x) = s \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(x-\overline{x})^2}{\sum(x_i-\overline{x})^2}}.$$

In your case, for $x=1$, you have $\widehat{\alpha} = 700$, $\widehat{\beta}=350$, $s\approx 180.2776$, $SE(\widehat{y}_{x=1}) \approx 127.4755$, $t_{0.975,2}\approx  4.302653
$. Hence your $0.95$-prediction interval is given by: 
$$\widehat{y}_{x=1} \pm t_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2},n-2}SE(\widehat{y}_{x=1}) = 1050 \pm  548.4828.$$

Comment: thanks for your answear, the input X seems strange, why is the input X 2 dimension vector ? With dummy coding on a 2 levels factor, i except to have only one column (arbitrarily isMale or isFemale)

Comment: there are indeed different forms of modelling the influence of the factor variable and different corresponding $X$-matrices. however you want to measure two effects (the effect of eacht of the levels of the gender-factor) and hence you need two columns. Try for example: ``model <- lm(salary ~ gender, data = df,contrasts = list(gender = "contr.sum"))`` and take a look at the model.matrix(model).